# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["userId"] not found. .JSONException

Tags: java, json, connection, httprequest, get-request

Now I have problem which is the json object can't find the key I don't know why. But the response was printed with all keys as you see in the error.

```
package com.ar.team.company.project;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Main.readJsonData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readJsonData() throws Exception {
        // Initializing:
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"; // Our url.
        URL obj = new URL(url); // Our url object(To open connection from it.).
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); // Our 
        httpURLConnection to connect to json.
        // Optional default is GET for getting the data:
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // Add request header:
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        // Getting the response code:
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        // Show to user the data:
        System.out.println("Sending 'GET' request to URL: " + url);
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
        // Start read the data:
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new                         
        InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); // Our buffered reader.
        String inputLine; // For checking the new line.
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // Here is our reading data.
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine); // Append the data for response(StringBuilder).
        }
        in.close(); // Closing the buffered reader.
        // Print in String:
        System.out.println("The response data: " + response);
        // Read JSON response and print:
        JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        System.out.println("Result After Reading JSON Response:".toUpperCase());
        // All Result:
        System.out.println("UserId: " + myResponse.getString("userId"));
        System.out.println("Id: " + myResponse.getString("id"));
        System.out.println("Title: " + myResponse.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Body: " + myResponse.getString("body"));
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
Response code: 200
The response data: {  "userId": 1,  "id": 1,  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat 
provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit 
recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas 
totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}
RESULT AFTER READING JSON RESPONSE:
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["userId"] not found.
   at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:516)
   at com.ar.team.company.project.Main.readJsonData(Main.java:48)
   at com.ar.team.company.project.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question in order to defeat the minimum length filter.

Comment: Okey thanks. i'm so sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors in code:

1. **Error: `JSONException: JSONObject["userId"] not found.`**

   `response` is a `StringBuilder`, so `new JSONObject(response)` is calling the [`JSONObject(Object bean)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.Object-) constructor. Since `StringBuilder` is not a Java Bean, it has no properties, and the `JSONObject` is empty.

   Change code to `new JSONObject(response.toString())` so it called the [`JSONObject(String source)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-) constructor.
2. **Error: `JSONException: JSONObject["userId"] not a string.`**

   The value of `userId` is a JSON Number, so you must call one of the get methods for retrieving a numeric value, e.g. [`getInt(String key)`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt-java.lang.String-), or any of the others: `getLong`, `getBigInteger`, `getDouble`, `getFloat`, `getNumber`.

   Change code to `getInt("userId")`.
3. **Error: `JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not a string.`**

   Same as #2: Change code to `getInt("id")`.